# How can I solve this rather simple looking integral equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, integral-equations

I was working on a physics problem and I have reduced it down to a simple integral equation with two boundary conditions:

$$\int_0^{l-t}y(x, t) dx = lh$$

With the conditions:

$$y(0, t) = y(l-t, t) = h$$

I am looking for $y(x, t)$. $l$, $h$ and $t$ are positive real numbers.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to solve it. So, I need a little help there.

Also, I am curious if this same problem could be converted into a differential equation.

Comment: Are $l$ and $h$ both constant?

Answer (score 0):

Let the antiderivative (wrt $x$) of $y(x,t)$ be $Y(x,t)$. Then

$$Y(l-t,t)-Y(0,t)=lh$$ and deriving on $l$,

$$y(l-t,t)=h.$$

The given conditions are automatically fulfilled, and the last identity establishes an implicit relation between $l$ and $t$, which depends on the particular expression of $y$. But you can't solve for $y$ just with the available information.

Comment: You just re-wrote the problem in a slightly different notation. :)

Comment: So, it's un-solvable in the sense that solution set is too broad, right?

Comment: @Anonymous: yep, the equation does not define $y$. My discussion is more than a rewrite.

Comment: And assumed that the equation holds for many values of $l$ (required to take derivative and get a valid equation), which is not mentioned in the question. In an exercise one would not be allowed to assume that, but since this is not you can ask them to clarify if you can assume it.

Comment: @orole: if $l$ is fixed, the RHS makes little sense.

Answer (score 0):

Has this something to do with FEM?

I would do:

at $x=0$, $$y(x, t)=h$$

at $x=\frac{1}{2} \cdot(l-t)$, $$y(x, t)=h+\frac{2ht}{l-t}$$

at $x=(l-t)$, $$y(x, t)=h$$

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Sorry, I must add to join points with lines and proceed with the integration.

Answer (score 0):

There are insufficient conditions to determine a unique solution. You can, however find a particular solution. The most obvious is one that's constant in $x$
$$ y(x,t) = \frac{hl}{l-t} $$

---

If you want to be fancy, you can also look for a Fourier-like solution
$$ y(x,t) = h + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n(t) \sin\left( \frac{n\pi}{l-t}x \right) $$

Then
$$ \int_0^{l-t} y(x,t)\ dx = h(l-t) + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_n(t)\frac{l-t}{n\pi}(1-(-1)^n) = lh $$

$$ \frac{2(l-t)}{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{c_{2k+1}(t)}{2k+1} = th $$

which gives a family of solutions
$$ y_n(x,t) = h + \frac{n\pi th}{2(l-t)}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{l-t}x\right), \quad n = 1,3,5, \dots $$